# How to use reduce tp filter items in array?

Tags: javascript

I have this array and I'm using filter and forEach function (it works just fine), but I would like to do it using **reduce** javascript function. Thanks a lot in advance?

Here's solution using filter and forEach

```
 arr
   .filter(el => typeof el.value === 'string' && el.value.includes('test'))
       .forEach(el => {
           if (el.key === 'cars') {
             el.value = el.value.replace('test', 'TICO');
           }
         }
   );
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is your expected output?

Comment: @Yousaf I'm trying to do the same thing but with the 'reduce' javascript function

Comment: Indeed I don't think you want to reduce the array and the `forEach` won't do anything, I think you want to `map` after `filtering` the array

Comment: Why do you want to use `.reduce()` method when the `.filter()` and `.map()` method are more appropriate to do what you are doing

Comment: `but I would like to do it using reduce javascript function` but why? `reduce` is the wrong tool for what you're doing, so why do you insist on using it? Why `reduce` and not `some` for example?

Comment: @Thomas well using filter to filter the items out is one iteration and then using forEach is another iteration, by using reduce it'll be a single iteration

Comment: But you don't need the `filter()`. You're currently (ab)using the filter just as another condition to the one inside of your `forEach`. You could as well just move the body of your filter-function inside the condition in your `forEach`

Comment: @Thomas could you please provide an answer with your suggested solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But you don't need the `filter()`. You're currently (ab)using the filter just as another condition to the one inside of your `forEach`. You could as well just move the body of your filter-function inside the condition in your `forEach`

```
arr.forEach(el => {
  if (typeof el.value === 'string' && el.value.includes('test') && el.key === 'cars') {
    el.value = el.value.replace('test', 'TICO');
  }
});
```

you could even go on and do

```
arr.forEach(el => {
  if (typeof el.value === 'string' && el.key === 'cars') {
    el.value = el.value.replace('test', 'TICO');
  }
});
```

I don't even think that this is less performant as `replace` has to "find" the string `test` anyways.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help bro!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this:

```
arr.reduce((all, el) => {
  if ((el) => typeof el.value === 'string' && el.value.includes('test'))
    all.push({
      ...el,
      value: el.key === 'cars' ? el.value.replace('test', 'TICO') : el.value,
    });

  return all;
}, []);
```

Comment: In the `push` part, it should be `...all` instead of `...el`. Anyway I think he/she doesn't want to use `reduce` instead of just a `filter` and a `map`

Comment: @AgustinMoles it should be `...el`, not `...all` because `all` is the whole array

Comment: @AgustinMoles actually  should be `...el` because we want to push the element with the value changed if the key is `cars`

Comment: @losif Thank you for you input bro!

Comment: @progx No problem 

Answer (score 1):

This will play the same func using `Array.reduce`.

```js
const result = arr.reduce((acc, el) => {
  if (typeof el.value === 'string' && el.value.includes('test')) {
    acc.push({
      ...el,
      value: el.key === 'cars' ? el.value.replace('test', 'TICO') : el.value
    });
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for you input bro!